# C# - Upload picture to firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to upload pictures to Firebase Storage? I tried to find something but without result. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't directly you could always use a byte string or similar solution

Comment: @CaptainWibble I tried to do like this, but without any result.